# Preg_match get the value

Tags: php, preg-match

How can get the exact way the value of a preg_match example of what i'm trying to do

website url: www.website.com/go/from-youtube-com ( this is show me just the videos added from youtube )

```
   $pattern = '/from-(.*?)-com/is';
   if(preg_match( $pattern, $search_query, $ar)) {
    $webvideos = $ar[1] . '.com';
    $webstatus = 1;
   }
```

This command is working but i test and if i make the url: www.website.com/go/asdasd-from-youtube-com or www.website.com/go/asdasd-from-youtube-com-ewrwer is still show me the videos from the youtube but normally was need to show false ...

Edit:

```
$search_query = 'from-youtube-com'; // (good url)
$search_query = 'dasdasd-from-youtube-com'; // (bad url)
$search_query = 'dasdasd-from-youtube-com-dasdsa'; // (bad url)
```

Comment: I don't quite get what exactly your question is.

Comment: example if url = from-youtube-com is good but if url is asdsada-from-youtube-com is false need to match the exact way of the url from-domain-com

Comment: You mean it must start with a slash or *start of string* and end with a slash or *end of string*? [See this demo](https://regex101.com/r/sV0wY4/2).

Comment: @bobblebubble i try the code and is works perfect! thank you!

Comment: @MateiZoc welcome! it's similar to @mmm's answer but with choice of `/` for start/end for delimiting. Correct answer depends on what exactly your `$search_query` would look like. Is it only part of a string or full url...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the "/" in your regex is the delimiter
if you want to use the slash in the regex, you have to choose another delimiter like "!" :

```
$pattern = '!/from-(.*?)-com/!is';
```

Comment: @MateiZoc *from-youtube-com is good but if url is asdsada-from-youtube-com is false* sounds more like you want anchors.

Answer (score 1):

As @mmm already pointed out you have to treat the `/` character in a special way.

a) Use another delimiter for your regex like

```
$pattern = '#/from-(.*?)-com/#is'; // use # instead of / delimiter
```

or b) escape the `/` like in

```
$pattern = '/\/from-(.*?)-com\//is'; // escape/ by using \/
```

Comment: $search_query = from-youtube-com